# How to pass inner struct type as argument of template?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

There is a macro [`offsetof(type, member)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) which calculates the offset of member of a class or struct.

I am trying to implement the equivalent functionality as a function template:

```
template<class T,typename U>
static constexpr size_t addressOf(U T::*member) {
    return (char*)&((T*)nullptr->*(member)) - (char*)nullptr;
}
```

But the `offsetof` macro additionally allows me to do something like:

```
struct A {

    struct B {
        int x;
    };

    int y;
    B b;
};

std::cout << offsetof(A, y) << std::endl;   // prints 0
std::cout << offsetof(A, b.x) << std::endl; // prints 4
```

How can I write the same thing in my `addressOf` function?

PS: Little more info: I have an array of raw data at external EEPROM Chip, which located at defined address. So i want to "map" structure to this data. Instead of "read" all struct from EERPOM to RAM, i want to get access to specific member of struct and "read" it only. In this case i calculate address of struct member in compile time and use function like: `ReadFromEEPROM(StartAddress+offsetof(A,b.x),&x);`
And i want to find a way to replace macro with template.

Comment: Your function template is ill-formed NDR because it'll never be usable in a constant expression (§7.1.5/6). Remove the `constexpr`.

Comment: Wait... that thing is full of filthy UB anyway.

Comment: Why would you want to use something like `offsetof()` in C++ anyway? You are much better off using pointers to members.

Comment: Why do you think that its UB? I want to calc address of any member of struct at compile time, so pointers is not a solution.